# Advanced git log - Different colors for different committers

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I currently have this alias set up on my Windows machine:
("lastcd" = "LastCommitterDate")

> [alias]
>
> lastcd = "!f() { git log -$1 --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) - %s %C(red)(%cn)%C(reset) %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset)'; }; f"

And the output would be as expected.
But all committers names are displayed in red. Is it possible to display other committers as red and my own commits as a different color??

**If the answer is "just do a script"**

I must disappoint you.. I have little experience with the whole script.. Unix.. thingy.. Born and raised in windows. I have tried setting up scripts for git but I could only get them to work inside the "C:\users\me.bashrc" file. And dumping a bunch of different copy-paste scripts in there seems like a bad practice..?

If someone could give me a walk through of the set up process for a "hello world" script that would work in git bash I would be a very happy man!

Best regards
Edvin

Comment: "Give me your hand and don't be afraid, I'll walk you trough." Is that what you are expecting? Come on!

Comment: No need to be sarcastic about it. I'm just asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure there is a way to colorize username only using git, so you might try the following:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) - %s %C(red)(%cn)%C(reset) %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset)" | sed "s/\(($(git config --get user.name)\)/$(tput setaf 4)\1/"  | less -R
```

The `sed` command finds and adds a blue color (`$(tput setaf 4)`) to your git user name (`$(git config --get user.name)`) .

`less -R` emulates the `git log` behavior showing all colors.

This works using `bash` on the OS I was *born and raised* ;-)